# Deleting from two different schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a Gym Web App for experience and I have come to a stage where I can not figure out how to solve this. I have Users and GymClasses.

When you book yourself into a gym class, it saves the `userId` in the `classMembers array`. Then also stores the class attached to the `user` in their schema.

So the issue is when trying to delete a class which has users signed up, it deletes the class as expected but I need to get every `userId` which is signed up into that class and delete the `classId` of their attending classes.

This is the images of the `class Schemas`:

[image]

As you can see the `Class Schema` has a `classMembers array` which is populated by `userId's` which are signed up to the class.

This is the user Schema:

```
const bookedClassesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  classId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'createClass',
  },
  dateBooked: {
    type: Date,
  }
})

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  gymLocation: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bookedClasses: [bookedClassesSchema]
});
```

Now from thought on this would be to before deleting the class, loop through the `classMembers array` grab every `userId` go to the user and since we already have the `ClassId` which we are deleting then delete that `ClassId` from the `bookedClasses array`. I am not sure on how I can do this so any advice would be great!

This is what I have done so far:

```
exports.deleteClass = (req, res) => {
  let classId = req.params.id;
  let users = [];
    GymClass.findById({
      _id: classId
    }, 'classMembers', (res ,err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Error Occured!"
        })
      } else {
        res.push(users);
        users.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element);
        });
          users.forEach( (users.userId) => {
            console.log(users.userId);
          });
```

I have not gone much further than this, any examples or help would be super appreciated!